# Django: How to populate other model fields when someone leaves a comment

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to let anyone post a comment on a blog but there are other fields in my model that need to get information that is not required in the form itself. I've tried adding it in the form_valid method but that method is not being called when the form is submitted. Any help is appreciated

## views.py

```
class CommentView(CreateView):
    template_name = "core/index.html"
    model = Comment
    form_class = CommentForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy("core:home")

    def form_valid(self, form):
        print("form is valid")
        form.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

## forms.py

```
class CommentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = [
            "text",
        ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["text"].widget.attrs.update(
            {"class": "form-control", "placeholder": "Enter Your Comment Here",}
        )
```

## models.py

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(
        BlogPost, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="comments"
    )
    text = models.TextField(max_length=255, default="")
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"({self.author})'s comment on ({self.post.title})"
```

## urls.py

```
app_name = "blog"
urlpatterns = [
    path("post/<int:pk>/", BlogPostDetailView.as_view(), name="detail"),
    path("post/category/<int:pk>/", CategoryListView.as_view(), name="category"),
    path("post/comment/<int:pk>/", CommentView.as_view(), name="comment"),
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
class CommentView(CreateView):
    template_name = "core/index.html"
    model = Comment
    form_class = CommentForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy("core:home")

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.post_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Here I am assuming you are passing value of `Post`(primary key) via `pk` attribute of url and`form.instance` has the new(not yet saved to DB) `Comment` object. Then I am attaching the value of `request.user`(current user) and post id with that instance.

Comment: Thank you that was very helpful! I realised afterwards that I forgot to put my "method=POST" in the form and thats why I was not receiving the information. All is working now. Thanks!